# An attribute argument must be a constant expression

Tags: .net

Is there any workaround for the following issue?

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression

I want to use decimals in an attribute’s parameter.

Answer (score 40):

Unfortunately you can't use decimals in attribute values, as the CLR itself doesn't really know about `System.Decimal` type - it's not a primitive type like int, double etc. The C# compiler basically fakes it for const fields of type decimal, but it can't achieve the same effect with attributes.

From the C# 3 spec, section 17.1.3:

> The types of positional and named
>   parameters for an attribute class are
>   limited to the attribute parameter
>   types, which are:
>
> - One of the following
>     types: bool, byte, char, double,
>     float, int, long, sbyte, short,
>     string, uint, ulong, ushort.
> - The type object.
> - The type System.Type.
> - An enum
>     type, provided it has public
>     accessibility and the types in which
>     it is nested (if any) also have public
>     accessibility (§17.2).
> - Single-dimensional arrays of the above
>     types.

Then later in section 17.2:

> An expression E is an attribute-argument-expression if all of the following statements are > true:
>
> - The type of E is an attribute
>     parameter type (§17.1.3).
> - At
>     compile-time, the value of E can be
>     resolved to one of the following:
>
>   - A
>       constant value.
>   - A System.Type object.
>   - A one-dimensional array of
>       attribute-argument-expressions.