# How should I write my unit tests for a child class?

Tags: java, junit

Say I have a class

```
public class Foo extends Bar
{
   public Response post()
   {
      return authorize();
   }

   // override some additional methods from Bar class
}
```

and another class

```
public class Bar
{
  public Response get()
  {
    return authorize();
  }

  public Response post()
  {
    return authorize();
  }

  public Response authorize()
  {
    // let's assume this method is "complicated" and has 200+ lines of code... lots of diff code paths etc
  }

}
```

So I was thinking of a few different approaches in terms of unit testing

1. I directly call `authorize` and test every single possible code path. Then I write 1 happy path unit test for the `get` and `post` methods for `Foo` and `Bar` for completeness.
2. I directly call `get` and `post` methods of both classes, and decide to only write tests for all combinations against one method only.
3. I completely ignore my `get` and `post` methods and assume that as long as I fully test my `authorize` method I'm good.

Am I complicating this? What's the best practice here.

Comment: I noticed this question was closed as it is considered "opinion-based". I think it is a question asking whether there are systematic testing techniques for inheritance. Yes there are, see the answers. I propose to re-open the question (and voted as such).

Answer (score 2):

You could consider extracting the `authorize` method into its own class, say `Authorizer`, and test that independently of `Foo` and `Bar`. Your tests for `Bar.get`, `Bar.post`, and `Foo.post` can mock out the `Authorizer` and verify that the `get` and `post` logic is correct.

This is essentially your first option, but with the "test every single possible code path" part encapsulated in a dedicated class.

A nice side effect of this approach is that you have also separated your concerns. The `Authorizer` only cares about authorization, and your `Foo` and `Bar` classes can concentrate on their `Foo`-behavior and `Bar`-behavior. This makes your code easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: thats a really neat approach. But my child class overrides some methods that are called in the `authorize` method to provide a class-specific implementation

Comment: That makes it harder :) Might still be worth refactoring things. If you can use composition rather then inheritance then you might be able to decouple your logic. For example, if `authorize` needs to call `getWidget`, then you might be able to factor that out to a `WidgetProvider` and provide one to the `Authorizer`. If `Foo` and `Bar` also need widgets, wire the same `WidgetProvider` in to those classes as well.

Answer (score 1):

It might also help to consider this as a problem of testing conformance to the Liskov Substitution Principle ([LSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/liskov-substitution-principle/info)).

The superclass `Bar` offers a contract. Any subclass of `Bar` must at least offer the same contract -- but it may require a little less (weaker preconditions, works under more circumstances) from its callers, and may promise a little more (stronger postconditions, do more work) to its callers.

From your test strategy 2, it seems that you can indeed create instances of `Bar`. This means you can create a class `BarTest`, which rigorously tests `Bar`, given an object of class `Bar`.

Now because of LSP, that very same test suite `BarTest`, must also pass on any subclass of `Bar`, hence also on `Foo`. One way to achieve this is to create a `FooTest` class that simply extends `BarTest`, and then runs the same tests on an object of class `Foo` (for example by overriding a factory method that actually creates the object under test).

Then, if `Foo` offers more functionality, you can add unit tests for this added functionality as well, in the same `FooTest` class.

In terms of your three options:

1. Test every single path in `authorize` and offer happy path for `get` and `post`: Write the test cases in `BarTest`, and `FooTest` will simply inherit them.
2. The inheritance would take care of testing both methods (`get`, `post`) in both contexts (`Bar`, `Foo`)
3. If things are simple, ignoring may be a good tradeoff. If the inheritance relation is more complicated, a systematic approach would help.

All this comes from Binder's [Polymorphic Server Test](http://books.google.nl/books?id=P3UkDhLHP4YC&pg=PA513&lpg=PA513&dq=robert+binder+polymorphic+server+test&source=bl&ots=_Efn5sbTG4&sig=cE9IGulcQ34IlZpOlYtcJ0l9nPc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MKtCT9n3D6HX0QXSqZCPDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=robert%20binder%20polymorphic%20server%20test&f=false) pattern, and McGregor's [PACT](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/%7Ejohnmc/joop/col4/column4.html) -- Parallel Architecture for Component Testing. See also [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9367854/165292) to a question about testing interface implementations.